# How do you determine the number of parameters inside Convolution Layers and Dense Layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Currently, I am working on my first neural network using convolutions to play around and test with the idea. My project currently involves a very simple system that uses supervised learning to classify a square and triangle.

One thing I am curious about is how to determine the number of, say, filters in a Convolution Layer. It seems people typically use values between 32 and 512, and I haven't been sure on what numbers to use for my own model. Same can be said for the Dense layers as well. I've seen people add multiple Dense and Convolution layers with varying numbers and I would like to be informed as to what exactly it all means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on type of dataset you have  and some hit and trial weights plus bias  which added during training,mostly we need to adjust weight during dropput,overall there is no particular rule for this.
Also try number of filters, different types of images have different patterns,adjusting those parameters will help model to capture those patters,how many layers is not fixed [try different layers and filters, researcher's have created standard architecture like Resnet and Alexnet please go through it for better understanding]